# Splitting audio into left and right channel into seperate files

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I'm having trouble seperating the channel buffers into a new file.

Here is the code for extracting each channels buffer:

```
        int samplesDesired = 10000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[samplesDesired * 4];
        short[] left = new short[samplesDesired];
        short[] right = new short[samplesDesired];

        using (WaveFileReader pcm = new WaveFileReader(filePath))
        {    
            int bytesRead = pcm.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead / 4; i++)
            {
                left[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
                index += 2;
                right[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, index);
                index += 2;
            }
        }
```

And here is how I try to create a file from the gathered buffers:

```
        using(var leftChannelFile = new WaveFileWriter("test.wav", new WaveFormat()))
        {
            leftChannelFile.WriteSamples(left, 0, left.Length);
        }
```

The problem is, when I try to play the "file.wav", it is 0 seconds long and 19,5 KB large. Any idea on why is that happening?

Comment: have you stepped through the code to see where the unexpected issues maybe happening.?

Comment: Yes I have, and found nothing out of the ordinary. My debugging skills aren't very sharp to be honest. Any suggestions on how to approch the matter? I've checked the extracted buffer - it's OK.

Comment: it appears that in your `pcm.Read(buffer, 0, 100000)` line that you are hard coding the length. shouldn't you be trying to read the length of the selected wave file..?

Comment: As @MethodMan said, I think you should be doing pcm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer. Length)

Answer (score 0):

Either you set the header of the resulting files indicating it is one channel/mono,

OR

you add a second *empty* channel to your result files (all 0 Bytes)